# Directory.Exists not getting mapped directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, directory

I have mapped a directory from another machine to my machine as `Z:` drive. This is further mapped inside a virtual directory on my local `IIS7`. On one of my pages I am using `Server.MapPath("~/dira/mapped_dir")` it is giving me correct path like: `Z:\\somedir\\mapped_dir`. I am able to open this directory and read-write files into it. But when in the ASPX page I execute `System.IO.Directory.Exists("Z:\\somedir\\mapped_dir")` it returns **false**.

Does this have anything with permissions or there is some other issue?. The source machine (which contains the physical folder) has given read-write access to all users on the shared folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know that using the SUBST command for virtual directories is a per-user setting and doesn't work with code running as a different user (e.g. a service). Sounds like it might be similar to your problems...

Comment: Yes it sounds like theASPX page is running within the IIS Process which is most likely not running as the user and does not have access to the mapped drive.

Comment: I'm also suspecting thati this is a premissions issue.