# File system paths  and Directory.Exists()

Tags: c#, .net, permissions, file-permissions

I'm at a bit of a loss on this one ... can't seem to understand what is going on.

I have an app that writes some files to a configured output directory, but before that, when the application loads I do this ...

```
string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TempDir"];
if (!Directory.Exists(path))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

My problem is that in my case the path is a network based location "\MyServer\Share" and when i use that path it works, but the path i'm using is actually "Z:\" because the share is mapped and is automatically mapped in all user sessions across the network.

I want to use "Z:\" but it doesn't work throwing back an error saying "all or part of the path doesn't exist".

I immediately thought "oh this must be permissions" so i checked it against say "G:\" which worked and has the same permissions applied ...

For all shares in question my user account has full control permissions on the location.

Initially i thought it might be something like this: [Directory.Exists not getting mapped directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254465/directory-exists-not-getting-mapped-directory)
But then i remembered that it couldn't be that the app is running under another account because I checked and

1. its only a console app
2. the line before is this:

   ```
   AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetThreadPrincipal(new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()));
   ```

.. as i understand the purpose of this is to ensure that the appdomain is running under the context of the current windows user, that includes all "threads created within the app domain" unless otherwise specified

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Looking through process monitor as Richard suggests ( see comments below) shows that if i use the full unc path "\MyServer\Share" the request is made as I would expect, if i use the mapped path "Z:\" it still requests the full unc path "\MyServer\Share" (presumably it is doing some form of translation in the inner workings of .net).

so no matter what i'm requesting a full unc path "\MyServer\Share" and yet only by explicitly specifying the full unc path can i access it ... weird !!!

The code posted above is exactly as I have written it in my console application, there's no other stuff going on yet other than that principle thing as these are the first lines of code to execute in my console application.

Hmmm ...

EDIT 2:

Ok now i'm really confused, when put a breakpoint on the configuration file request line above and run it up to the breakpoint then clear out process monitor and step over that and the if statement nothing appears in the process monitor as I would expect it to ...

Why would that happen?

Comment: What does [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645) show the application is doing?

Comment: Good question  ... give me 2 minutes to check this out

Comment: Are you having the [linked connections](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019185) problem? [Less verbose version](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937624).

Comment: Hmmm interesting GSerg you could be on to something.

Comment: Ok i switched off UAC and tried executing the app on its own without the debugger ... UAc makes no difference to the results, but executing the app outside of visual studio reveals that it does in fact request the unc path .. odd that it doesn't when being debugged though don't you think ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have found an odd bug in the debugging tools / .net framework ...
When the debugger is attached to my app it fails, when the debugger is not attached it works as expected.

The recommendation is always to use a full unc path but the calls to Directory.Exists(path) and Directory.Delete(path) resolve mapped drives before making the call as process monitor reveals so although it is recommended it is not required.

I have found however that running the app then attaching visual studio manually seems to allow the app to run as epected and allow the require debugging in my situation.

This solution comes with the "Works on my PC garantee" only ... i take no responsibility for anything said in this question :)

Thank you to everyone for the help however I seem to have resolved it ... UAc was good advice and so was process monitor ... thanks guys ... really helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You can not use mapped drive as a path you need to make a shared directory and give it the permission you need (read or write) and then connect to it like this: 
\ServerName\SharedDirectoryName\OneMoreDirectory

Comment: Technically I should be able to have an application use any path i give it assuming the application is running under my credentials and has all the access rights i have ... could please explain why you feel I can't use a mapped drive? ... it still resolves to a full UNC path behind the scenes as process monitor seems to show.

Comment: The problem is that the drive is mapped to your username. Unless you're starting the service under your user account that mapped drive doesn't exist. Generally the service starts under the Local System Account. You have two options here. First is to start the service under your user account(from some reason it doesn't always worked for me). Second is to use the full UNC path rather than the mapped Drive Path.

Comment: This is a console app and I have stated that I explicitly tell the app domain to run under my credentials (see point on principal use above) ... also the UNc path is resolved at runtime dynamically.